# What to do if the object is destroyed during the call in C++

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, shared-ptr, stdatomic

Here is my test code

```cpp
class bar
{
public:
    explicit bar(int x) : num(x) {}
    int get_num()
    {
        return num;
    }

private:
    int num;
};

shared_ptr<bar> ptr_store;

void get_func()
{
    while (1)
        printf("get_num:%d\n", ptr_store->get_num());
};

void set_func()
{
    while (1)
        //ptr_store = make_shared<bar>(1);
        atomic_exchange(&ptr_store, make_shared<bar>(1));

}

int main()
{
    ptr_store = make_shared<bar>(-1);
    std::thread t1(get_func);
    std::thread t2(set_func);
    t1.join();
    t2.join();
}
```

I wonder why this program wouldn't make a core dump?

If `set_func` in `t2` destroy the origin `ptr_store` when `t1` is using `ptr_store->get_num()`, it could cause some fault?
Is it Guaranteed by `shared_ptr`? Or it just a coincidence.

```
Test environment:
OS: Ubuntu 20.04 LTS
Clang: clang version 3.9.1
G++: gcc version 7.5.0
```

update:
I think there is no possibility that two threads access one object.
`atomic_exchange` or `reset` can be considered an atomic operation.
When setting the new object, the old object will not be changed.

Answer (score 7):

> I wonder why this program wouldn't make a core dump?

There is no such thing as "core dump" in the C++ standard. These words are not in the vocabulary. There is "undefined behaviour", and your program has it. There is a [data race](https://godbolt.org/z/9zTb4P).

> If multiple threads of execution access the same std::shared_ptr object without synchronization and any of those accesses uses a non-const member function of shared_ptr then a data race will occur unless all such access is performed through these functions [source](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/atomic).

`atomic_exchange` is OK but you [need `atomic_load`](https://godbolt.org/z/vaePEj) in the other thread.

Note all of this is deprecated in C++20. Use `std::atomic<std::shared_ptr<bar>>` instead.

Comment: However, note that this version of `atomic_load` is deprecated in C++20! You should make the global pointer a `std::atomic<std::shared_ptr<bar>>` instead.

Comment: @SebastianRedl yes, atomic_exchange is also deprecated, added a note.

Comment: ... and UB does *not* mean "required to crash".  It literally means anything could happen, and you'll have to look at the asm generated by one specific implementation for one specific CPU to figure out what.  Other effects are common, like use-after-free when freed memory just goes on the free list instead of being unmapped.

Answer (score 0):

And now I fix my code by @n. 'pronouns' m.'s answer.
It seems like work well now

```cpp
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <utility>
#include <thread>
#include <chrono>
#include <functional>
#include <atomic>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <bits/shared_ptr_atomic.h>

using namespace std;

class bar
{
public:
    explicit bar(vector<int> &in) : num(-1)
    {
        for (auto iter : in)
            v.push_back(iter);
    }
    int get_num()
    {
        for (auto iter : v)
        {
            num = max(iter, num);
        }
        if (num >= 100)
        {
            printf("Fault %d\n", num);
        }
        return num;
    }

private:
    int num;
    vector<int> v;
};

shared_ptr<bar> ptr_store;

int st;

void get_func()
{
    for (int k = 0; k <= 10000; k++)
    {
        auto temp = atomic_load_explicit(&ptr_store, std::memory_order_seq_cst);
        printf("Get_num %d\n", temp->get_num());
    }
}

void set_func()
{
    for (int k = 0; k <= 10000; k++)
    {
        vector<int> v;
        int sz = rand() % 100;
        for (int i = 0; i < sz; i++)
            v.push_back(rand() % 100);
        atomic_exchange(&ptr_store, make_shared<bar>(v));
    }
}

int main()
{
    srand((unsigned)time(NULL));
    vector<int> v = {1, 2, 3};
    ptr_store = make_shared<bar>(v);
    std::thread t1(get_func);
    std::thread t2(set_func);
    t1.join();
    t2.join();
}

// g++ atomic_exchange.cpp -o atomic_exchange -pthread && ./atomic_exchange > atomic_exchange.out
```